# How can I update the CSS and links in marathon UI?

Tags: deployment, docker, mesos, marathon

I used docker,Marathon and Mesos in my server infrastructure. I want to change few things in Marathon UI.
Is it possible? If yes then from where I can find the installed codebase of Marathon UI.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marathon is open source on GitHub so you could pull the source, change it how you want, and build it yourself, customised.

The UI is even a separate GitHub project so you can change it separately.

https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon
https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-ui/tree/master/src

The Marathon Readme on Github has the instructions to build from source:

"To build Marathon from source, check out this repo and submodules and use sbt to build a JAR:"

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon.git
cd marathon
sbt assembly
```

"Run `./bin/build-distribution` to package Marathon as an executable JAR (optional)."

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.